# How does a 1D multi-channel convolutional layer (Keras) train?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working with time series EEG data recorded from 10 individual locations on the body to classify future behavior in terms of increasing heart activity. I would like to better understand how my labeled data corresponds to the training inputs.

So far, several RNN configurations as well as countless combinations of vanilla dense networks have not gotten me great results and I'd figure a 1D convnet is worth a try.

The things I'm having trouble understanding are:

1.) Feeding data into the model.

```python
orig shape         = (30000 timesteps, 10 channels)  
array fed to layer = (300 slices, 100 timesteps, 10 channels)
```

Are the slices separated by 1 time step, giving me 300 slices of timesteps at either end of the original array, or are they separated end to end? If the second is true, how could I create an array of (30000 - 100) slices separated by one ts and is also compatible with the 1D CNN layer?

2) Matching labels with the training and testing data

My understanding is that when you feed in a sequence of `train_x_shape = (30000, 10)`, there are 30000 labels with `train_y_shape = (30000, 2)` (2 classes) associated with the `train_x` data.

So, when (300 slices of) 100 timesteps of `train_x` data with `shape = (300, 100, 10)` are fed into the model, does the label value correspond to the entire 100 ts (one label per 100 ts, with this label being equal to the last time step's label), or are each 100 rows/vectors in the slice labeled- one for each ts?

Train input:

```python
train_x = train_x.reshape(train_x.shape[0], 1, train_x.shape[1])  
n_timesteps = 100 
n_channels  = 10
layer : model.add(Convolution1D(filters = n_channels * 2, padding = 'same', kernel_size = 3, input_shape = (n_timesteps, n_channels))) 
final layer : model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'softmax'))
```

I use `categorical_crossentropy` for loss.

Comment: Please provide code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've edited the post above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer 1

This will really depend on "how did you get those slices"?
The answer is totally dependent on what "you're doing". So, what do you want?

If you have simply reshaped (`array.reshape(...)`) the original array from shape `(30000,10)` to shape `(300,100,10)`, the model will see:

- 300 individual (and not connected) sequences
- 100 timesteps in each sequence

Sequence 1 goes from step 0 to 299;
Sequence 2 goes from step 300 to 599 and so on.

**Creating overlapping slices - Sliding window**

If you want to create sequences shifted by only one timestep, make a loop for that.

```
import numpy as np

originalSequence = someArrayWithShape((30000,10))  
newSlices = [] #empty list

start = 0
end = start + 300

while end <= 30000:
    newSlices.append(originalSequence[start:end])
    start+=1
    end+=1

newSlices = np.asarray(newSlices)
```

Beware: if you do this in the input data, you will have to do a similar thing in your output data as well.

### Answer2

Again, that's totally up to you. What do you want to achieve?

Convolutional layers will keep the timesteps with these options:

- If you use `padding='same'`, the final length will be the same as the input
- If you don't, the final length will be reduced depending on the kernel size you choose

Recurrent layers will keep the timesteps or not depending on:

- Whether you use `return_sequences=True` - Output has timesteps
- Or you use `return_sequences=False` - Output has no timesteps

#### If you want only one output for each sequence (not per timestep):

**Recurrent models:**

- Use `LSTM(...., return_sequences=True)` until the last LSTM
- The last LSTM will be `LSTM(..., return_sequences=False)`

**Convolutional models**:

At some point after the convolutions, choose one of these to add:

- `GlobalMaxPooling1D`
- `GlobalAveragePooling1D`
- `Flatten` (but treat the number of channels later with a `Dense(2)`
- `Reshape((2,))`

I think I'd go with GlobalMaxPooling2D if using convoltions, but recurrent models seem better for this. (Not a rule, though).

You can choose to use intermediate `MaxPooling1D` layers to gradually reduce the length from 100 to 50, then to 25 and so on. This will probably reach a better output.

---

Remember to keep X and Y paired:

```
import numpy as np

train_x = someArrayWithShape((30000,10))  
train_y = someArrayWithShape((30000,2))
newXSlices = [] #empty list
newYSlices = [] #empty list

start = 0
end = start + 300

while end <= 30000:
    newXSlices.append(train_x[start:end])
    newYSlices.append(train_y[end-1:end])
    start+=1
    end+=1

newXSlices = np.asarray(newXSlices)
newYSlices = np.asarray(newYSlices)
```

Comment: thank you for getting back, I realized my post wasn't too clear and needed some formatting so I edited it if you'd like to look at it again

Comment: you answered the first question perfectly, but for the second question I am still unsure as to how each time step in a slice contributes to the learning process of the CNN

Comment: It's up to you to choose. Do you want them to participate or not? If you leave them in the output, they will contribute, if you don't (maybe by using a flatten or reshape layer), only a final result will participate. It's really totally your choice.

Comment: currently, I do not want any time steps within the slice included in the output, just the entire sequence of timesteps, and I only want the label for the final ts of a slice to be designated to the whole slice.   Essentially, I am expecting the network to train on several sequences of 100 ts and associating one label (defined in the last sentence) with the calculations and other inner-workings of the network for each slice. Are my inputs set up correctly so that the network is outputting what I described?

Comment: works like a charm, thank you! The shapes are train_x.shape = (30000, 300, 10) and train_y.shape = (30000, 1, 2)

just being thorough- my current layer setup is: Input > Conv1D + MaxPool1D + BatchNorm + LeakyReLU + Dropout > Conv1D + MaxPool1D + BatchNorm + LeakyReLU + Dropout > Dense(2) + SoftMax > Cat_Cross_Ent > Fit . I will be testing TimeDistributed CNN layers as well as LSTM and GRU in the future, but for this Conv1D example, you're suggesting I throw in a GlobalMaxPooling2D at the end (before the final Dense(2) layer), or a flatten layer to deal with the intermediate time steps?

Comment: I meant `GlobalMaxPooling1D`. Yes, I think it's a good option to add it before the dense layer to eliminate the timesteps.

Comment: If you consider this answers your question, please mark it as answered :)

Comment: An interesting option in your case might be a recurrent model with all layers using `return_sequences=True`. This will predict all timesteps from the original X and Y with shapes `(1,30000,10)` and `(1,30000,2)`. --- I can't say it's better or worse, though.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I've been playing around with the convolution layers and I got a noticeable bump in precision (from ~50% to 59%) and just ventured back into recurrent layers using your method. One thing I noticed is that epoch time jumped up significantly (from 10s to 30s) and loss has been absolutely unpredictable- ranging from 0.29 to 2981039.09 after 10 epochs, while still being reliably over 60% training accuracy (test precision still in the 50s).